# GUI driven web app with Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a web application and an considering Django as a web framework. I have a significant amount of Python experience, but none in web development (keen to learn!).

I need to develop an interface to enable the user to drag & drop electrical components onto a canvas and link them to form a circuit.

Would Django be a suitable platform for this type of application?

If not, could someone please suggest an alternative?

Comment: Django's good for this. The "GUI" will be your django templates and your "drag and drop" part can be handled by jquery (or other javascript frameworks) and ajax calls to do real time updates of your boards querying django

Comment: It is very hard to say. You could pretty much achieve the same thing with pure frontend javascript libraries and just post the result of gui to a backend.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Django is for server side scripting, and You need to create mostly client-side app.

Consider using RaphaelJS, it's a great Javascript library for SVG graphics [link](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Then, You should save data that user created, and that is where you should use Django.

Also, users login and registration is Django's stuff.